# Differences and derivatives.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to figure out how to think about differentes, i.e $\Delta$. 
If I have an equation, $W=\Delta E$, is it at all possible to have this as a continuous function?

I understand a derivative is the rate of change of a function, if I take the derivative of a function in respect to time, then multiply this by time 1, do I have a function of differences?

I also would like to know how to think about multiple deltas. If I have a function $y = \Delta (k\Delta x)$, how would I calculate y? If I have a continuous function, would I have to extract values at certain intervals (every 1 x), and take the differences from these values, multiply by k and take the differences in these values? If that is so, I'm "losing" 2 data points?